# Filtering Rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, data-cleaning

My data looks like this: Number(String), Number2(String), Transaction Type(String), Cost(Integer)

[image]

enter image description here

For number 1, Cost 10 and -10 cancel out so the remaining cost is 100

For number 2, Cost 50 and -50 cancel out, Cost 87 and -87 cancel out

For number 3, Cost remains 274

For number 4, Cost 316 and -316 cancel out, 313 remains as the cost

The output I am looking for Looks like this:
 [image]

How do I do this in SQL?

I have tried "sum(price)" and group by "number", but oracle doesn't let me get results because of other columns

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47572/filtering-unique-row-values-in-sql

Comment: Please post example data as text, not images.

Comment: Added data types for better clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has very nice functionality equivalent toe `first()` . . . but the syntax is a little cumbersome:

```
select number,
       max(number2) keep (dense_rank first order by cost desc) as number2,
       max(transaction_type) keep (dense_rank first order by cost desc) as transaction_type,
       max(cost) as cost
from t
group by number;
```

In my experience, `keep` has good performance characteristics.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Just an update, The columns Number, Number 2 and Transaction Type are Strings and not integers.

Comment: @FirstSlack . . . So?  This code work just as well on strings as on integers or dates.

Comment: The code works, I need to add more columns to this report, How do I add more columns in Oracle, Do I need to use the same keep () and first() functions when adding more columns to the result.

Comment: @FirstSlack . . . If none of the answers here generalize for you, then you should accept one of them and ask a *new* question.

Comment: @FirstSlack . . . As the OP, you can click on the check mark next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing an aggregate query, you have to pick *one value* for each column - either by including it in the `group by`, or wrapping it in an aggregate function.

It's not clear what you want to display for columns 2 and 3 in your output, but from your example data it looks like you're taking the MAX, so that's what I did here.

```
select number, max(number2), max(transaction_type), sum(cost)
from my_data
group by number
having sum(cost) <> 0;
```

Comment: Number, Number 2 and Transaction Types are Strings and not integers

Comment: Number 2 and Transaction_types are strings which I want in my output, which will later be used for different analysis, I just need the items from this columns displayed in output. The filtering has to be done on column1(Number) which is a string and column(4) which is an integer.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter if they're stringers or numbers - you have multiple values of "Number 2" for each "Number" that you're grouping by, so *you have to pick one of them to display*. In my example, `max()` is just picking the one that comes last alphabetically. Please try running it and let me know how the output doesn't match what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there... you'll need to get the sum for each number without the other columns and then join back to your table.

```
select * from table t
join
(select number,sum(cost)
from table
group by number) sums on sums.number=t.number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.cost = (select sum(t1.cost) from table t1 where t1.number = t.number);
```